# UICollectionView number of cells in the section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

How to count the number of cells in the section? I need to know the number of cells in the section during the cell selection.

Comment: - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this method for the the collection view to find number of items in a section

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

You can call it using your UICollectionView object as.

```
NSInteger numberOfItems = [myCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:2];
```

Where 2 is the section for which you want to find the number of items.